# What is the solution to this series?

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series

I have a linear algebra equation which is $B \partial_\tau B^+$, where $B$ is an exponential kernel
$ B = \exp(-t/\tau)$ for $t>0, \tau>0$ and $B^+$ is its pseudo-inverse matrix.
and ${\partial_\tau}_{N \times N}$ is the derivative operator with -1 on diagonal elements and +1 on the below diagonal elements. $N \times N$ is the size of the matrix.

I ended up with a series like this:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^N (-1)^{2N + 1} e^{-n \frac{dt}{\tau}}
$$
Can I use the same geometric series to find where this series converges as $N$ increases?